# Messed up while installing octave in Ubuntu 14.04. Having trouble doing apt-get upgrade & apt-get -f install now

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, octave

```
Output of apt-get upgrade:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Setting up octave (3.8.1-1ubuntu1) ...
error: couldn't read directory /usr/share/octave/packages: No such file or directory
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/pkg/private/rebuild.m at line 29, column 7
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 495, column 25
dpkg: error processing package octave (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:octave
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Output of apt-get -f install:
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up octave (3.8.1-1ubuntu1) ...
error: couldn't read directory /usr/share/octave/packages: No such file or directory
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/pkg/private/rebuild.m at line 29, column 7
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.1/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 495, column 25
dpkg: error processing package octave (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:octave
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```